# How to get a string and convert to a fragment name to start a Class?

Tags: java, android, class, fragment

Sorry for bad english, I'm Brazilian and I'm using a translator.

I have an application with tabs, and I want to simply and dynamically add tabs with titles, or icons, or title and icons together.

So I started to build the following class:

```
 public static class TabItens {
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSPAdapter
        String titulo;
        int resId;

        public TabItens(TabLayout tabLayout, SectionsPagerAdapter mSPAdapter) {
            this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
            this.mSPAdapter = mSPAdapter;
        }

        public void AddTabItem(String tabfragment, String titulo) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(titulo));
            mSPAdapter.addFragment(new tabfragment);
        }

        public void AddTabItemIco(String tabfragment, String titulo, int resId) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(resId).setText(titulo));
            mSPAdapter.addFragment(new tabfragment);
        }
    }
```

I'm having trouble with the lines it contains: `mSPAdapter.addFragment(new tabfragment);`

Which must be compatible with this function:

```
 public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
```

How can I solve this ??

If necessary, follow the complete activity class: https://pastebin.com/hFLUpHF2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `tabfragment` is a `String` in your code, you can't call `new tabfragment`. it is incorrect and your code won't compile if it is as you posted here.

You can create fragment object from the name of fragment class with `Class.forName()` method, let's say that all your fragments are in a same package and you have the `packagename` of it in a 
String named `fragmentPackage` in correct format for example something like `com.app.frags`, then you should do as follow:

```
try{
   Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(fragmentPackage+ "." + tabfragment).newInstance();
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So your `addFragment` method should be:

```
public void addFragment(String tabfragment) {
  try{
     Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(fragmentPackage+ "." + tabfragment).newInstance();
     mFragmentList.add(fragment);
   } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is almost working, but it is still giving error in this line: `Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(fragmentPackage+ "." + tabfragment);`. I have tried in many ways, but always the same mistake: `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class<capture<?>>' to 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. From what I could understand, it is an incompatibility with (Fragment) and Class.forName. How can I solve this?

Comment: Now i can solve. was missing `.newInstance()` at the end. I did it the following way and it worked: `Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(getPackageName()+".fragments."+tabfragment).newInstance();` . Thank you ^^

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `newInstance`, I updated answer to correct it.

Comment: No problem. Anyway it helped me a lot. Thank you